# Integrate html content as home page

Tags: theme, magento-1.8, integrate

I created a `.html`  file which I coded in the way my new projects home website's design  should be. Now I want this `.html` file to integrate inside my newly installed magento folder as **Home page**.

The `.html` file has some main parts which should not be changed when the user visits some other pages such as:

- Header
- Footer

where should I start from?

I know some ways to integrate this page like adding as new theme or as CMS block but I don't know much about both of the aproaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to slice a static html file to the templating of Magento?

The header and footer that are used through out the whole shop are located in `template/page/html/header.phtml` and `template/page/html/footer.phtml` with some small parts coming from different `phtml` files which you can track down using the template hints you can activate under `System > Configuration > Developer > [change to website scope] > Path hints`

For your homepage, this is by default a CMS page called `home` which you can edit through the content section and the layout XML section when you open it under `CMS > Pages`.

I found this to be somewhat limited and definitely not practical so I wrote an extension ([which can be found on Github](https://github.com/sandermangel/rkhomepagewrapper)) to have `phtml` files and some extra functionality for retrieving categories on the homepage.
You are free to use it.

Also I would like to suggest reading up on building your own theme. Altho it's not what you want to do it will however teach you a lot on how to slice your html file into Magento's theme

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/package
- http://youtu.be/AXqx_maVTIM
- http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/magento-creating-your-own-design-package-with-theme-variants

Comment: After asking I realized that I can do this using template hints.. :) thanks..

Comment: No problem, I hope i've helped you with one or two resources. Good luck!

Comment: yeah, I will look in to it.